# Java: Console doesn't show any output

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I run my program, nothing shows up. In the console window, all that is visible is blank, white space.

Screenshot:
[image]

Here is a paste of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foothill
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // declare the references
      //warning for line below
      HeartRates heartrates;
      //warning for line above: the value of the local variable heartrates is not used

      // instantiate the object
      heartrates = new HeartRates();
   }
}

class HeartRates {

   // member data
   public String firstName, lastName;
   public int birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear, personAge, maxRate, minRange, maxRange;

   // default constructor
   HeartRates() {
   }

   // 2-parameter constructor
   HeartRates (String userFirstname, String userLastname, int userBirthmonth, int userBirthday, int userBirthYear, int userAge, int heartMax, int userMin, int userMax){
      firstName = userFirstname;
      lastName = userLastname;
      birthMonth = userBirthmonth;
      birthDay = userBirthday;
      birthYear = userBirthYear;
      personAge = userAge;
      maxRate = heartMax;
      minRange = userMin;
      maxRange = userMax;
   }

   // accessor "get" methods --------------------------------
   public String getFirstname(String userFirstname, String firstName) {
      firstName = userFirstname;
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (System.in);
      userFirstname = inputStream.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Your first name is: " + userFirstname);
      inputStream.close();
      return firstName;
   }
   public String getLastName(String userLastname, String lastName){
      lastName = userLastname;
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (System.in);
      userLastname = inputStream.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Your last name is: " +userLastname);
      inputStream.close();
      return lastName;
   }
   public int getBirthmonth(int userBirthmonth, int birthMonth){
      birthMonth = userBirthmonth;
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (System.in);
      userBirthmonth = inputStream.nextInt();
      int monthBirth = Integer.parseInt("userBirthmonth");
      System.out.print(monthBirth);
      inputStream.close();
      return birthMonth;
   }
   public int getBirthday(int userBirthday, int birthDay){
      birthDay = userBirthday;
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (System.in);
      userBirthday = inputStream.nextInt();
      int dayBirth = Integer.parseInt("userBirthday");
      System.out.print(dayBirth);
      inputStream.close();
      return birthDay;
   }
   public int getBirthyear(int userBirthyear, int birthYear){
      birthYear = userBirthyear;
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (System.in);
      userBirthyear = inputStream.nextInt();
      int yearBirth = Integer.parseInt("userBirthyear");
      System.out.print(yearBirth);
      inputStream.close();
      return birthYear;
   }
   public int getAge(int birthMonth, int birthDay, int birthYear, int userAge){
      personAge = userAge;
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the current month in numbers: ");
      int theMonth = inputStream.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Please enter the current day in numbers: ");
      int theDay = inputStream.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Please enter the current year in numbers: ");
      int theYear = inputStream.nextInt();
      userAge = theYear - birthYear;
         if ((theMonth == birthMonth && theDay < birthDay) || theMonth < birthMonth){
            userAge--;
            System.out.println("Your date of birth is: " + birthMonth + "/" + birthDay + "/" + birthYear);
            System.out.println("You are " + userAge + " years old.");
         }
         else {
            System.out.println("Your are " + userAge + " years old.");
         }
      inputStream.close();
      return userAge;
   }
   public int getMaximumHeartRate(int heartMax, int userAge, int maxRate){
      maxRate = heartMax;
      heartMax = 220 - userAge;
      return maxRate;
   }
   public double getMinTargetHeartRate(int heartMax, int userMin, int minRange){
      minRange = userMin;
      userMin = (int)(heartMax*0.5);
      return minRange;
   }
   public int getMaxTargetHeartRate(int heartMax, int userMax, int maxRange){
      maxRange = userMax;
      userMax = (int)(heartMax*0.85);
      return maxRange;
   }
   public void getTargetHeartRange(int heartMax, int userMin, int userMax){
      System.out.println("Your maximum heart rate is " + heartMax + "beats per minute.");
      System.out.print("Your target-heart-rate range is from " + userMin + " to " + userMax + " beats per minute.");
   }

   // accessor "set" method -------------------------------
   public void setFirstname(String userFirstname, String firstName){
      firstName = userFirstname;
   }
   public void setLastname(String userLastname, String lastName){
      lastName = userLastname;
   }
   public void setBirthmonth(int userBirthmonth, int birthMonth){
      birthMonth = userBirthmonth;
   }
   public void setBirthday(int userBirthday, int birthDay){
      birthDay = userBirthday;
   }
   public void setBirthyear(int userBirthyear, int birthYear){
      birthYear = userBirthyear;
   }
   public void setAge(int userAge, int personAge){
      personAge = userAge;
   }
   public void setMaximumHeartRate(int heartMax, int maxRate){
      maxRate = heartMax;
   }
   public void setMinTargetHeartRate(int userMin, int minRange){
      minRange = userMin;
   }
   public void setMaxTargetHeartRate(int userMax, int maxRange){
      maxRange = userMax;
   }

}
```

I'm a beginner to Java, and from my code you can probably tell I'm struggling to grasp the concept of creating classes, methods, and instantiating objects. In fact, we're supposed to print out all the information from the object, but I don't quite understand what that means. Most of what I have are based from examples online or from my book.
I know there have been similar questions asked, but I think mine is slightly different. Thank you so much.

Comment: You create an empty HeartRates object in main but don't do anything with it such as call methods on it -- what do you expect to see in the console and why? To best understand what's going on, please walk through your code mentally to see what it is doing at every step. Remember, only the code that is called in the main method will run.

Answer (score 1):

The functions which print something to the console in your code is `public int getAge(...)` or `getTargetHeartRange(..)` which are never called. You only called the no-argument constructor on your object and then did nothing else. You have to actually call the functions if you want them to work.

Something like:

```
heartrates.getTargetHeartRange(fill in your arguments);
```

In your case if you want to print something meaningful, I suggest you actually set some values for those member variables (i.e. use your setter functions after instantiating the object).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the immediate cause of your problems is that your program doesn't seem to be doing anything apart from creating a `HeartRate` instance.  You will only get some output if one of the methods with a `System.out.println(...)` call is actually called by your code.

If you just want to see some output, just change this:

```
  heartrates = new HeartRates();
```

to

```
  System.out.println("Offering low rates on second hand hearts!");
  heartrates = new HeartRates();
```

A second problem is that your code is creating a new `Scanner(System.in)` object each time you want to read.  That is a bad idea, and it is liable to cause problems.  Depending on the `Scanner` methods that you call (and the nature of the input stream), you may end up doing a "read-ahead".  If that happens, then the characters that have been read will not be available to be read again from `System.in`.

What you should do is to create a `Scanner(System.in)` object just once, and put it into a private field.

(Better still from a design perspective, refactor your code so that the `HeartRate` object is not responsible for reading / parsing the user's input at all.  However, that's probably a "lesson" that you are not ready for just yet.)